# pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting this error whenever I attempt to execute my `pygame` code:
`pygame.error: video system not initialized`

```py
from sys import exit
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

black = 0, 0, 0
white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0
green = 0, 255, 0
blue = 0, 0, 255

screen = screen_width, screen_height = 600, 400

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.display.set_caption("Physics")

def game_loop():
  fps_cap = 120
  running = True
  while running:
      clock.tick(fps_cap)

      for event in pygame.event.get():  # error is here
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              running = False

      screen.fill(white)

      pygame.display.flip()

  pygame.quit()
  exit()

game_loop()
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygame.error: video system not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261774/pygame-error-video-system-not-initialized)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You haven't called [`pygame.init()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) anywhere.

See the [basic Intro tutorial](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/PygameIntro.html), or the specific [Import and Initialize](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html) tutorial, which explains:

> Before you can do much with pygame, you will need to initialize it. The most common way to do this is just make one call.

```
pygame.init()
```

> This will attempt to initialize all the pygame modules for you. Not all pygame modules need to be initialized, but this will automatically initialize the ones that do. You can also easily initialize each pygame module by hand. For example to only initialize the font module you would just call.

In your particular case, it's probably [`pygame.display`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init) that's complaining that you called either its `set_caption` or its `flip` without calling its `init` first. But really, as the tutorial says, it's better to just `init` everything at the top than to try to figure out exactly what needs to be initialized when.

Answer (score 2):

Changing code to this, avoids that error.
while running:
clock.tick(fps_cap)

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): #error is here
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
        pygame.quit()
if running:
     screen.fill(white)
     pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications to your code:

```
import os
import sys
import math
import pygame
import pygame.mixer
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
black = 0, 0, 0
white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0
green = 0, 255, 0
blue = 0, 0, 255

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.display.set_caption("Physics")


while True:
    clock.tick(120)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    screen.fill(green)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

**#this will fool the system to think it has video access**

```
import os
import sys
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was a problem because I didn't set `pygame.quit()` out of the loop at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because you try to set the window title (with `set_caption()`) but you haven't created a pygame window, so your `screen` variable is just a tuple containing the size of your future window.

To create a pygame window, you have to call `pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)`.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you doing `pygame.init()` then solve the problem video system initialized. 
   but you get the next error like:

> (`AttributeError: tuple object has no attribute 'fill'`) this.

---

2. this problem is solving when you doing this

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
```

but not doing like

```
screen = screen_width, screen_height = 600, 400
```

---

3. Then the full problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
exit()
```

To stop running code
example :

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): #error is here
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
        exit() # Solution
```

Answer (score -1):

If you using `class` for your `pygame` window don't use `pygame.init()` in your `class`. Use `pygame.init()` at below libraries.

Answer (score -2):

You have to add:

```
pygame.init()
```

Before you quit the display you should stop the while loop.

Answer (score -2):

1. You need to initialized pygame using this command `pygame.init`

   ```
   If the problem is not solved then following this step
   ```
2. this problem happens when you using a beta version.
3. so my suggestion is please use the new, old version(If now lunch 3.8 python, you
   need to install python 3.7)
4. Now goto python terminal and install pygame (pip install pygame)
5. now the problem is solved...