# Pygame error: video system not initialized stuck in game loop

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyqt, pygame

Ok so i have this snake game that i made using pygame its very basic and it works but i created a login program that i need to rund the game from and whenever i try to close the game i get a error that looks like this The thing is that when i tried putting sys.exit() after the pygame.exit() in the snake code my login program closes and just runs a blank python window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\Summative\LukaLogin.py", line 119, in Snake
    snake = snakeSummative.main()        
  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\Summative\snakeSummative.py", line 178, in main
    playAgain(final)
  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\Summative\snakeSummative.py", line 161, in   playAgain
    for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

**Snake Game:**

```
def playAgain(final):
    gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)
    username = 'luka'
    message_to_screen("Game Over, press c to play again press q to quit", RED)
    message_to_screen1(str(final),GREEN)
    file = open('Scores.txt','a')
    file.write( username + ' ' + 'Snake' + ' ' + str(final) + ' ' + '\n')
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        score = 0
                        return True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        pygame.quit()
                        break              
def main():
    while True:
        final = gameLoop()
        playAgain(final)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Login def that calls the snake game:**

```
class GameHub(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_GameHub):
    def __init__ (self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.play_BlackJack.clicked.connect(self.BlackJack)
        self.play_Snake.clicked.connect(self.Snake)
        self.play_Scores.clicked.connect(self.HighScores)
        self.play_Logout.clicked.connect(self.LogOut)
    def Snake(self):
        import snakeSummative
        snake = snakeSummative.main()
```

Any help would be apreciated im really stumped to as why i get the error even though i break the loop

Answer (score 0):

You are quitting pygame and then trying to use it again:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_q:
    pygame.quit()
    break
```

this quits pygame then breaks the while loop surrounding it, then function is called again in `main()` but this time pygame has been quit. You need to break the outer loop in order to quit the game which is never being done.

```
def playAgain(final):
    gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)
    username = 'luka'
    message_to_screen("Game Over, press c to play again press q to quit", RED)
    message_to_screen1(str(final),GREEN)
    file = open('Scores.txt','a')
    file.write( username + ' ' + 'Snake' + ' ' + str(final) + ' ' + '\n')
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        score = 0
                        return True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        return False         
def main():
    while True:
        final = gameLoop()
        if not playAgain(final): break
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think this is the behaviour you were going for, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767644/6289743) might answer your question.

Make sure you have called `pygame.init()` before starting the game program.

Comment: Why do you post this as an answer? I already marked it as duplicate.

Comment: Did not notice it @LPK