# Pygame Error: video system not initialized (more info in description)

Tags: python, pygame

I get same error as this person: [pygame.error: video system not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767591/pygame-error-video-system-not-initialized), but I have called pg.init().

Two unexpected things happened,

1. link didnt appear (the background did, and they're in the same directory
2. after i close the pygame window i get the error mentioned in title

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame as pg

pg.init()

overflate = pg.display.set_mode((500,350))

pg.display.set_caption("Spill")
bg = pg.image.load("castle.jpg")
link = pg.image.load("link.png")
linkx = 0
linky = 0

overflate.blit(link,(linkx, linky))
pg.display.update()

overflate.blit(bg,(0, 0))
pg.display.update()

while True:
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.K_w:
                spillerx+=10
        if e.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
    pg.display.update()
```

Comment: You need to break out of your loop after receiving the QUIT event.  And the "link" image did not appear because you drew the "bg" image over it.

Comment: That worked, thanks. How do I reduce the size of the link picture?

Answer (score 0):

You have to *blit* the image after drawing the background:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.K_w:
            spillerx+=10
        if e.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    overflate.blit(bg,(0, 0))
    overflate.blit(link,(linkx, linky))
    pg.display.update()

pg.quit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)