# Error: video system not initialized when using pygame

Tags: python

I keep having the error whenever I try to run this code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
print(pygame.display.Info())

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.quit:
                run = False

pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've tried adding `pygame.init()` but it didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygame.error: video system not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767591/pygame-error-video-system-not-initialized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here. The immediate cause of the error is that your call to `pygame.quit()` isn't inside the `main` function, so it gets called *immediately* when the program starts. You need to fix that:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
print(pygame.display.Info())

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.quit:
                run = False
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will allow your program to run...but it's never going to quit. You're comparing `event.type == pygame.quit`, but `pygame.quit` is a function; this comparison will always be `False`. You need to compare it to `pygame.QUIT`, which is an integer value that will match `event.type` as expected:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
print(pygame.display.Info())

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```