# How to fix the for event in pygame..event..get(): problem?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

If anyone can help me how can I solve this problem ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLNKA.png)

I try to open the pygame window with visual studio code with by indenting my code and I fallow the instructions of the video of a developer I'm following but it also give me this error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDvvg.png)
can somebody please help me with this problem?

I try to also retype it and made some changes but noting still works

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767591/pygame-error-video-system-not-initialized pygame.error: video system not initialized

Comment: Typo.  You have `_init_` instead of `__init__`.  There need to be two underscores before and after.

Comment: thanks but still didn't work ma9

Comment: Thanks to you both ma9 and Tim I finally got it to work thanks to both of you for trying to help me

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Comment: If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)