# Pygame 'DIsplay mode not set'?

Tags: python, pygame, game-loop

I (tried) to create a game menu and placed my GameLoop in the Class = Menü. When I try to start the code it highlights the line `pygame.display.update()` and tells me that: `Display mode not set.`

```
Class Menü(Highscore):

    def __init__(self):
        Highscore.__init__(self)
        #Fenster erstellen
        self.fenster_height = 1000  # Fensterhöhe definieren
        self.fenster_width = 600  # Fensterbreite definieren
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.fenster_height, self.fenster_width))
        self.run = True
        #self.start_img = self.image.load('pong_test.png').convert_alpha()  # Bild für start_img ausw#hlen
        #self.quit_img = self.image.load('pong_test.png').convert_alpha()
        #self.auslesen = Highscore.readHS()

        pygame.display.set_caption('Spielekiste')
        #pygame.start_img = pygame.image.load('pong_test.png').convert_alpha()
        #pygame.quit_img = pygame.image.load('pong_test.png').convert_alpha()
        #self.screen.fill((96, 144, 189))  # Screen mit Farbe (255,255,255) füllen

    def runMenü(self):


        while True:  # Während "run = TRUE"
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                       # fenster schließen
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                    pygame.quit()
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    print('test')

            pygame.display.update()  # Fenster wird aktualisiert
menu = Menü

menu.runMenü(menu)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to create a class in python, we use the `class` keyword, whereas in your code, you used the word `Class`, which will throw an error since it isn't a keyword in python.

So replace this line: `Class Menü(Highscore):` with this line: `class Menü(Highscore):`

Now to address your issue, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261774/pygame-error-video-system-not-initialized/10264053). Basically, there are two ways in which you can prevent the error that you are getting:

### The First Way

```
run = True
while run:  # Während "run = TRUE"
    for event in pygame.event.get():
               # fenster schließen
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print('test')

    pygame.display.update()  # Fenster wird aktualisiert

pygame.quit()
```

In your current game loop (the `while` loop inside the `runMenü` function), when the `pygame.QUIT` event is triggered, you immediately quit the program without stopping your game loop. So if you replace the code inside your `runMenü` function with the code I wrote, you won't get an error.

### The Second Way

```
while True:  # Während "run = TRUE"
    for event in pygame.event.get():
               # fenster schließen
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print('test')

    pygame.display.update()  # Fenster wird aktualisiert
```

Here, I'm exiting the program after using `pygame.quit()` to quit pygame. That way, your program won't throw an error because I'm terminating it with `sys.exit(0)`. Don't forget to add `import sys` at the top of your code (under `import pygame`).

I would personally use the first method because it stops the loop and then terminates the program, which I think is better.

## Modified Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Menü(Highscore):
    def __init__(self):
        Highscore.__init__(self)
        #Fenster erstellen
        self.fenster_height = 1000  # Fensterhöhe definieren
        self.fenster_width = 600  # Fensterbreite definieren
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.fenster_height, self.fenster_width))
        self.run = True
        #self.start_img = self.image.load('pong_test.png').convert_alpha()  # Bild für start_img ausw#hlen
        #self.quit_img = self.image.load('pong_test.png').convert_alpha()
        #self.auslesen = Highscore.readHS()

        pygame.display.set_caption('Spielekiste')
        #pygame.start_img = pygame.image.load('pong_test.png').convert_alpha()
        #pygame.quit_img = pygame.image.load('pong_test.png').convert_alpha()
        #self.screen.fill((96, 144, 189))  # Screen mit Farbe (255,255,255) füllen

    def runMenü(self):
        run = True
        while run:  # Während "run = TRUE"
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                       # fenster schließen
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    print('test')

            pygame.display.update()  # Fenster wird aktualisiert

        pygame.quit()


menu = Menü()
menu.runMenü()
```

Comment: Oh nice it works. Thanks man :')

Comment: @Shpend I'm happy to hear that :) Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark. That way, other people with the same issue will be able to see this answer and benefit from it.